# Tikz matrix - positioning of table out of bound

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I am trying to draw a table using tikz and the matrix tool, but when I plot in pdf the table is located out of the margins.

I am trying to localize the matrix at the position (0,0) but it is impossible to move. I used the template provided by "arrow shape table" example found in overleaf and from them I am modifying to my convinience.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,matrix,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\definecolor{colone}{RGB}{209,220,204}
\definecolor{coltwo}{RGB}{204,222,210}
\definecolor{colthree}{RGB}{207,233,232}
\definecolor{colfour}{RGB}{248,243,214}
\definecolor{colfive}{RGB}{245,238,197}
\definecolor{colsix}{RGB}{243,235,179}
\definecolor{colseven}{RGB}{241,231,163}

\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,text width=2cm,align=center},
  text depth=1.25ex,
  text height=2.5ex,
  nodes in empty cells}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (mat) at (0,0) [table] 
{
    {}      & |[fill=colfour]|  & |[fill=colfour]|
      & |[fill=colfour]|  & |[fill=colfour]|  &                   \\
    % |[fill=colfive]|      & |[fill=colfive]|  & |[fill=colfive]|
    %   & |[fill=colfive]|  & |[fill=colfive]|  &                   \\
    % |[fill=colsix]|       & |[fill=colsix]|   & |[fill=colsix]|
    %   & |[fill=colsix]|   & |[fill=colsix]|   &   \\
    % |[fill=colseven]|     & |[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]|
    %   & |[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]| &  \\
    |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=colthree]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
      & |[fill=colthree]|   & |[fill=colthree]|   &   \\
    % |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
    %   & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   & \\
    % |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
    %   & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   & \\
    % |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
    %   & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   & \\
};

% horizontal rules
\foreach \row in {1,2}
% \draw[white] (mat-\row-1.north west) -- (mat-\row-5.north east);
% \draw[white] (mat-\row-1.south west) -- (mat-\row-5.south east);
\draw[white,ultra thick] (mat-1-1.north west) -- (mat-1-5.north east);
\draw[white,ultra thick] (mat-1-1.south west) -- (mat-1-5.south east);
\draw[white,ultra thick] (mat-2-1.south west) -- (mat-2-5.south east);

% vertical rules
\foreach \col in {1,2,3,4,5}
  \draw[white,ultra thick] (mat-2-\col.north west) -- (mat-2-\col.south west);

% Setup table Template
\node[below=1mm,fit=(mat-1-2)(mat-1-5)]{\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering Week 43}};
\node[] at (mat-2-1){\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering Groups}};
\node[] at (mat-2-2){\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering Monday}};
\node[] at (mat-2-3){\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering Tuesday}};
\node[] at (mat-2-4){\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering Wednesday}};
\node[] at (mat-2-5){\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering Thursday}};
\node[] at (mat-2-6){\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering Friday}};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `tikzpicture` coordinates are only relevant inside the `tikzpicture`. Once the figure is finished, it is considered like any other character by `LaTeX`. Therefore the use of `\matrix (mat) at (0,0) [table]` has no sense bucause it just means that the matrix center will be placed in coordinate `(0,0)` into the `tikzpicture` but it means nothing regarding its position on paper.

Your result is missplaced because you use `\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering Groups}` inside nodes. As these nodes don't fit on one textline, the whole figure is aligned to right. But you don't have to declare such `nodes`, you can insert cells contents into the `matrix` node. Also you don't need to draw white lines between cells because you can declare an empty space with `row sep` and `column sep`.

Except the multicolumn node `week 43` everything else can be made with the `matrix` it self. This is what is shown in following code. This code cuold be simplified using `styles` for `rows` or `columns`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,matrix,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\definecolor{colone}{RGB}{209,220,204}
\definecolor{coltwo}{RGB}{204,222,210}
\definecolor{colthree}{RGB}{207,233,232}
\definecolor{colfour}{RGB}{248,243,214}
\definecolor{colfive}{RGB}{245,238,197}
\definecolor{colsix}{RGB}{243,235,179}
\definecolor{colseven}{RGB}{241,231,163}

\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=.8pt,
  column sep=.8pt,
  nodes={rectangle,text width=2cm,align=center},
  text depth=1.25ex,
  text height=2.5ex,
  nodes in empty cells}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (mat) at (0,0) [table] 
{
    {}      & |[fill=colfour]|  & |[fill=colfour]|
      & |[fill=colfour]|  & |[fill=colfour]|  &                   \\
    % |[fill=colfive]|      & |[fill=colfive]|  & |[fill=colfive]|
    %   & |[fill=colfive]|  & |[fill=colfive]|  &                   \\
    % |[fill=colsix]|       & |[fill=colsix]|   & |[fill=colsix]|
    %   & |[fill=colsix]|   & |[fill=colsix]|   &   \\
    % |[fill=colseven]|     & |[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]|
    %   & |[fill=colseven]| & |[fill=colseven]| &  \\
    |[fill=colone]|  Groups     & |[fill=colthree]| Monday  & |[fill=colthree]|
    Tuesday  & |[fill=colthree]| Wednesday  & |[fill=colthree]| Thursday  & |[fill=colthree]| Friday  \\
    % |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
    %   & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   & \\
    % |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
    %   & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   & \\
    % |[fill=colone]|       & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colthree]|
    %   & |[fill=coltwo]|   & |[fill=colone]|   & \\
};
%
%% horizontal rules
%\foreach \row in {1,2}
%%% \draw[white] (mat-\row-1.north west) -- (mat-\row-5.north east);
%%% \draw[white] (mat-\row-1.south west) -- (mat-\row-5.south east);
%\draw[white,ultra thick] (mat-1-1.north west) -- (mat-1-6.north east);
%\draw[white,ultra thick] (mat-1-1.south west) -- (mat-1-6.south east);
%\draw[white,ultra thick] (mat-2-1.south west) -- (mat-2-6.south east);
%
%% vertical rules
%\foreach \col in {1,2,3,4,5}
%  \draw[white,ultra thick] (mat-2-\col.north west) -- (mat-2-\col.south west);
%
%% Setup table Template
\node[fill=colfour,fit=(mat-1-2)(mat-1-6), inner sep=0pt, label=center:{Week 43}]{};
%\node[] at (mat-2-1){\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering Groups}};
%\node[] at (mat-2-2){\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering Monday}};
%\node[] at (mat-2-3){\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering Tuesday}};
%\node[] at (mat-2-4){\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering Wednesday}};
%\node[] at (mat-2-5){\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering Thursday}};
%\node[] at (mat-2-6){\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering Friday}};
%
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]